# VLAN centralised management

Tags: vlan, trunk

I wonder if there is a proper way to setup a 10 DLINK switches VLAN system. My aim is to have one computer/central switch that would broadcast the whole VLAN setting across the other switches and as an extra I could configure each port remotely.

At this point everything is working fine but I have to setup each switches individually. I have heart TRUNKING mode but 1 I am not tooo familiar with it 2, I am not sure if that could manage the whole ports across the switches.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

(DGS 3100TG, 3x DGS 1500-48, 2x DWS 1224, 4x DGS 1515)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are even asking, but maybe this DLink software is what you are looking for (DLink Centralized Network management): http://www.dlink.com/us/en/business-solutions/switching/network-and-switch-accessories/d-view-network-management-software/dv-600s-d-view-6-snmp-network-management-software-standard-edition ??  Or maybe you can explain your question a little more??  What does "I have heart TRUNKING mode" even mean?

Comment: Thanks for the lesson:) I meant that Vlan trunk is a way to tell switches what vlans you want to link however I think I understand that is only a way to link the switches together with VLAN. I will have a look at the link certainly. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cisco parlance, VTP (VLAN Trunking Protocol) is used to "propagate" VLAN configuration information to all switches in the same VTP domain. Note that port VLAN membership is not propagated to all switches in the same VTP domain, only the VLAN's themselves are propagated. Each switch may have different ports in each VLAN than any other switch participating in the same VTP domain. Also note that VTP is not the same thing as "trunking VLAN's" or port trunking, which is a port configuration that allows a port to carry VLAN traffic for multiple VLAN's.

Answer (score 0):

@thecleaner gave me answer, thanks a lot.

I'm not sure what you are even asking, but maybe this DLink software is what you are looking for (DLink Centralized Network management): dlink.com/us/en/business-solutions/switching/…